# How does "from numpy import ndarray" work?

Tags: python, package

I looked at the source code of [`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy),  [`numpy/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.py), [`numpy/core/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/__init__.py) and some other files in the source tree, but did not find `ndarray`. What trick do they use to enable the command

```
from numpy import ndarray
```

to work?

[of course the same question can be asked for many other Python libraries; `numpy` and `ndarray` are just an example. I am asking because I would like to know how to achieve a similar effect in a package I am writing]

Comment: I think, its going to be implemented in c. 
Possibly in this [file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a numpy expert, but my guess is that it's imported in
[numeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/numeric.py)

```
from .multiarray import (
    [...]
    min_scalar_type, ndarray, nditer, nested_iters, promote_types,
    )
```

and then in [`core/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/36eb76c9ded81c6626a86aa06d137dd800350751/numpy/core/__init__.py#L73):

```
from .numeric import *
```

BTW, the c definition is in a Cython header [`numpy/__init__.pxd`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/623bc1fae1d47df24e7f1e29321d0c0ba2771ce0/numpy/__init__.pxd#L239)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a "trick". You can import into `__init__.py` and "hoist" objects up through levels in the package.

What you're importing from is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/36eb76c9ded81c6626a86aa06d137dd800350751/numpy/__init__.py#L151):

`from .core import *`

This makes any object in `.core` accessible at the package level. They use the same "trick" again [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/36eb76c9ded81c6626a86aa06d137dd800350751/numpy/core/__init__.py#L2) to pull `ndarray` from one of the modules, so it gets hoisted multiple times, which then makes it available to `from .core import *` and then a second time to be available as `from numpy import ndarray`.